# Scorer function: difference between make_scorer/score_func and

Tags: python, python-2.7, scikit-learn, grid-search

In scikit's (0.18.1) documentation I find what follows a bit confusing. Seems that writing your own scoring function is doable in multiple ways. But what's the difference?

[GridSearchCV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) takes a `scoring` argument as a:

> scorer callable object / function with signature `scorer(estimator, X, y)`

This option is supported also in [model evaluation docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#implementing-your-own-scoring-object).

Conversely, [make_scorer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.make_scorer.html#sklearn.metrics.make_scorer) wants a `score_func` as a:

> score function (or loss function) with signature `score_func(y, y_pred, **kwargs)`

## Example

Both `GridSearchCV(scoring=dummy_scorer)` and `GridSearchCV(scoring=make_scorer(dummy_scorer2))` print what expected.

```
def dummy_scorer(estimator, X, y):
    print X
    print y
    return 1

def dummy_scorer2(y1, y2):
    print y1
    print y2
    return 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You see, scikit-learn has different utility functions (`precision_score, recall_score, accuracy_score` etc) which can  be used to directly specify the actual and predicted values and calculate the result.  Even writing the custom scorer must use the actual and predicted values in most cases. 
 So the signature has to be `(y, y_pred, ...)`.

Now, in techniques like GridSearch or RandomizedSearch, the score on the cross-validated data has to be automatically. As the estimator and  X keeps changing (X changes due to cross-validation), so do the predicted values and corresponding actual values. 
So `scorer(estimator, X, y)` makes sense. Take the estimator and `X`, call `estimator.predict(X)` to get the predicted output, compare it with actual (`y`) and calculate result.

What `make_scorer()` does is just return a pointer to the actual function which does all that what I described above.

From the [source-code in scikit-learn](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/metrics/scorer.py), we can validate the above things:

```
Line347 : cls = _PredictScorer
          return cls(score_func, sign, kwargs)
```

Here `cls` is a pointer to the function at [this line](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/metrics/scorer.py#L75):

```
Line100 : y_pred = estimator.predict(X)
          if sample_weight is not None:
              return self._sign * self._score_func(y_true, y_pred, 
                                                 sample_weight=sample_weight,
                                                             **self._kwargs)
          else:
              return self._sign * self._score_func(y_true, y_pred, **self._kwargs)
```

Also, when you actually use the string values like "accuracy", "precision" etc in `scoring` parameter in GridSearchCV, then also, it is first converted into `scorer(estimator, X, y, ...)` by using make_scorer, which can be verified in [this line at the same source file](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/metrics/scorer.py#351)

Hope it makes some sense. Please feel free to ask if any doubt or question about it.

Comment: don't get "the score on the cross-validated data has to be automatically", do you mean the utility function is called automatically (within the GridSearch loop?)

Comment: ok after looking at your examples and to the whole picture (_PredictScorer)[https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/metrics/scorer.py#L74] I see how it works. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I meant that within each cross validation loop, the score is calculated automatically by calling the scorer (on both the training and test data)

Comment: Thanks for this - the `scorer(estimator, X, y)` is not in docs! Understanding that it is doing `predict(X)` and scoring on `y` is the clincher!