# User criterion and of "make_scorer"

Tags: python, scikit-learn

1. Do I need to pass parameters(y_true, y_pred) to the function «make_scorer»?
   If so, how are they transmitted..? If can be example.
2. How to set a custom criterion in "scoring"?
3. The result of each iteration is the result of a training or test?

---

```
_scorer = make_scorer(f1_score,pos_label=0)

grid_searcher = GridSearchCV(clf, parameter_grid, verbose=200, scoring=_scorer)
grid_searcher.fit(X_train, y_train)
clf_best = grid_searcher.best_estimator_
```

- Each iteration when it is produced in a process:

---

```
[CV] class_weight=balanced, max_depth=10, n_estimators=100 ........... 
[CV] class_weight=balanced, max_depth=10, n_estimators=100, score=0.4419706300331596, total= 16.4s 
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done 12 out of 12 | elapsed: 1.7min remaining: 0.0s 
[CV] class_weight=balanced, max_depth=10, n_estimators=150 > – user287629 47 mins ago
```

---

```
y_pred = clf.predict (X_test) 
r = np.sum (y_pred == 0) & (y_pred == y_test) 
s = np.sum (y_pred == 1) & (y_pred! = y_test) 
z = r / s #I need to get a z
```

Comment: See this question for point 1:- https://stackoverflow.com/q/43523210/3374996

Comment: For point 2: which custom criterion are you talking about? Do you have your own score/loss function. Post that here.

Comment: Point 3: Which iteration? Fold iteration? Scoring will be calculated on test set.

Comment: Please explain in more detail (with an example maybe). Whats a "z"?

Comment: Above corrected the first message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
def T_scorer(y_true, y_pred, **kwargs):
    epsilon = 1e-8  # think of the "computational stability" ("ZeroDivisionError")
    r = np.sum((y_pred == 0) & (y_pred == y_true))
    s = np.sum((y_pred == 1) & (y_pred != y_true))
    z = r / (s + epsilon)  # I need to get a z
    return z

_scorer = make_scorer(T_scorer)

grid_searcher = GridSearchCV(clf, parameter_grid, verbose=2, scoring=_scorer)
```

Comment: The values do not match. It is not clear where the variables come from(y_true, y_pred)? **kwargs (inactive, gray.)

Comment: @user287629, please provide a small reproducible sample data set and your desired data set (score) in your question

Comment: Thank you!  In General understood)